# UnicodeError when importing python file

Tags: python, import, pycharm

I am trying to import a python file `Sonderbuch_BASECASE_3ph.py` into another python file `test.py`. `test.py` is in the main dir `foo` while `Sonderbuch_BASECASE_3ph.py` is in a subdir `grid_data`.

[image]

`Sonderbuch_BASECASE_3ph.py` has a function with the same name, which I need to import as well:

```
# Sonderbuch_BASECASE_3ph
from numpy import array
def Sonderbuch_BASECASE_3ph():
    .....
```

Both of these attempts to import result in a `SyntaxError`:

```
from grid_data import Sonderbuch_BASECASE_3ph
import grid_data.Sonderbuch_BASECASE_3ph
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Artur/Desktop/foo/test.py", line 1, in <module>
    from grid_data import Sonderbuch_BASECASE_3ph
  File "C:\Users\Artur\Desktop\foo\grid_data\Sonderbuch_BASECASE_3ph.py", line 1550
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe4 in position 29: invalid continuation byte
```

**Edit:**

The encoding of the file seems to be `windows-1252`, at least that is what pycharm is proposing. Decoding the file in `windows-1252` does not solve the ErrorMsg though. `Sonderbuch_BASECASE_3hp.py` is just a storage file for a dictionary. I was hoping I could just import it.

[image]

None of the encodings seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

What's in your `Sonderbuch_BASECASE_3ph.py` file exactly?

I guess that the files use different encoding hence importing one to another may result in error. My guess is that your `test.py` is in UTF-8 while the other file is encoded with latin-1 or something like that. Check what's the encoding of the files (you can do it in PyCharm, Sublime, Notepad++, etc.). In Pycharm, you can see the encoding of a file at the bottom right (by default).

Comment: I've tried changing the encoding. Please see the Edit section.

Comment: Well, I just copied the contents of the file into another clone python file, which resolved the encoding problem.

Comment: Great to  hear that!